# Is it safe to cleanup OpenSSL multiple times?

Tags: c++, c, openssl

My application used two third-party libraries. Both of them are used OpenSSL library as .dll(it mean that both libraries have single shared instance of OpenSSL).

Both of them have similar `OpenSSL_CleanUp` functions:

```
void OpenSSL_CleanUp() {
  CRYPTO_set_locking_callback(NULL);//1
  CRYPTO_set_id_callback(NULL);//1
  EVP_cleanup();//1 and 2
  CRYPTO_cleanup_all_ex_data();//1 and 2
  ERR_remove_state(0);//1 and 2
  ERR_free_strings();//1 and 2
}
//1 - this line is present in first lib
//2 - this line is present in second lib
```

Life time of these libraries is different. The First one can be reloaded multiple time. The second one will live until application shutdown.

My application looks like it works fine, but I fear not obvious side-effect.